# How to debug/time my php function? Create Zip file

Tags: php, amazon-s3

Have a php function to generate a zip file "on fly". I have the files on one server (AWS S3) but the PHP function to generate the zip-file is on another server/web hosting. I have noticed that it takes long time to generate the zip-file and I get a corrupt zip file if there are many files when I create zip file. I want to troubleshoot/debug where it takes "stop", what the missing link is if there are many files (the limit seems to be 20 files, which is not many).

How can I find out where in my function it fails if I have more than 20 files to generate my zip-file from?

Can I add a timer to every row?

Can I find out if it is memory or something else on my shared hosting (where I have the php function)? Or if it is something with S3.

My php function to generate the zip file from files on AWS S3

```
<?php
$imageQueryResult = $this->getUserImages('download', array('i.image_name'));

if(!empty($imageQueryResult)) {
  $imageUrl = $this->getFromAmazon('download', $imageQueryResult);

  $imageNumber = 1;
  $zipName = 'tt-'.date("Y-m-d").'.zip';

       //create new zip object
  $zip = new ZipArchive();

       //create a temp file &amp; open it
  $tmp_file = tempnam('.','');
  $zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

       //loop through each file
  foreach($imageUrl as $image){
          //Get extension
    $ext = pathinfo(parse_url($image, PHP_URL_PATH), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

           //download file
    $download_file = file_get_contents($image);

           //add it to the zip
    $zip->addFromString(basename($imageNumber.'-tt.'.$ext),$download_file);


    $imageNumber++;
  }

       //close zip
  $zip->close();

      //send the file to the browser as a download
  header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipName);
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($tmp_file));
  header('Content-type: application/zip');
  readfile($tmp_file);
  ignore_user_abort(true);
  unlink($tmp_file);
  ?>
```

Comment: my first thought would be to check maximal execution time, that might also be an issue. It is normally set to 30seconds which is plenty (I think at least) but maybe it was set to some smaller value?

Comment: max_execution_time = 60

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.getstatusstring.php

ZipArchive::getStatusString — Returns the status error message, system and/or zip messages

Comment: Added 40 files and wrote getStatusString to a txt-file for each image. Result, 40 lines with "No error" but corrupt zip-file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't know how long it will take to compress all your files. So you'll have to check the maximal execution time and the memory that consumes that script.

If the problem is with the time, the solution might be to do this in chunks:

1. open the archive for writing
2. add N files per iteration
3. close the archive
4. Repeat until you you have files

Keep in mind that with this approach the more files you have, the more memory you need to store the temporary results

Comment: Added a timer in my php function and 40 files took 27 seconds. My max_execution_time = 60 in php settings. I got a corrupt zip-file.